# Change root document of main website with .htaccess without affecting subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

Files structure:

```
public_html
    website
    subdomain1
    subdomain2
    .htaccess
```

When I visit `example.com` it should load files from `website` directory without doing the same with subdomains.

I tried this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !website/
RewriteRule (.*) /website/$1 [L]
```

This is working fine with I visit `example.com` but when I visit `subdomain1.example.com` or `subdomain2.example.com` I get 403 forbidden error I think this is because it tries to load files from `website` inside these subdomains which doesn't exist.

How to exclude subdomains from `.htaccess` condition?

Note: I'm not using www with main domain not subdomains.

Comment: Why not just change the `DocumentRoot` of the website to point to `public_html/website` rather than to `public_html`?   It is bad practice to have nested document roots like your configuration.

Comment: If you are using shared hosting that sets up like this for you, I'd recommend adding website as a subdomain (add-on domain) and setting the main domain to something that doesn't resolve in DNS.